# Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I need some help, let me tell you my context, we have two test environments, in one of them the web app is directed to one data base in postgres, the app run just fine here, in the other environment we have two databases a slave one and the main one, and in the app is showing an error related to the database.

There are a table named discussions and the other is named network_discussion, when i saved a discussion immediately i saved into network_discussion, but in the second environment is not working, i thought it was something related to a GRANT access but apparently is not, this is the error trace:

```
2012-09-15 15:10:27,162|TP-Processor12|ERROR|mp_sites|web|mpmvstage|/home/matchpoint-web/yfroot||Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Batch entry 0 insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (33214047252677632, 33495522229786655, company-corp.com_newdisa, 2012-09-15 15:10:27.153000 -07:00, 33495522229786656) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (33214047252677632, 33495522229786655, company-corp.com_newdisa, 2012-09-15 15:10:27.153000 -07:00, 33495522229786656) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Batch entry 0 insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (33214047252677632, 33495522229786655, company-corp.com_newdisa, 2012-09-15 15:10:27.153000 -07:00, 33495522229786656) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (33214047252677632, 33495522229786655, company-corp.com_newdisa, 2012-09-15 15:10:27.153000 -07:00, 33495522229786656) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into users.network_discussion (network_id, user_discussion_id, title, last_updated_dt, id) values (33214047252677632, 33495522229786655, company-corp.com_newdisa, 2012-09-15 15:10:27.153000 -07:00, 33495522229786656) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2512)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1314)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:347)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2574)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:500)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:473)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.doCommitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:623)
    at com.netblue.matchpoint.service.DiscussionService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b685dad0.addOrGetDiscussions(<generated>)
    at com.netblue.matchpoint.filter.DiscussionFilter.doFilter(DiscussionFilter.java:30)
    at com.netblue.matchpoint.sitecontroller.MpBaseSiteController.getFilteredParams(MpBaseSiteContr
```

it continues, i mean the error trace continue more, so any help to gave me an idea would be great, i trace this already in google, but no results, thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide your hibernate mappings and entities. By the way as the stack trace suggests "Call getNextException to see the cause", you can call getNextException on the exception to get to the root cause

Comment: I actually get fixed it, i'll explain it in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the trouble, it was really painful but thank God i could. As i told, it works in some environment with a database, but in the other environment doesn't work, the trouble was that i had a multiple saving and dependant registers, but the first takes some time to get saved, so when i saved the second register (different tables the second one dependant on the first one) the data for the key's wasn't saved already, so i couldn't saved in cascade as is usual cuz it would take to change a lot of code, as this is not a 'begin from zero' development, so what i did was to dig more into the code and get where the data was exactly saved, and put there the saving of the other register. So basically if you're tracing that weird error, is nothing special than corrupted data trying to get saved in DB.

Answer (score 1):

When `BatchUpdateException.getNextException` doesn't help (or it just returns `null`) it's also possible to [disable batching in hibernate](http://inoio.de/blog/2012/11/16/how-to-get-rid-of-hibernate-genericjdbcexception/): set `hibernate.jdbc.factory_class=org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcherFactory` in the hibernate session configuration (of course this should only be done to solve the issue and shouldn't be set forever).